# What is this device? (8+2 pin + string + label = "Test")

Tags: identification

I found [this](https://coord.info/TB6YFMY) [trackable](https://www.geocaching.com/track/#TrackableFaqs) but it does not say in the description what is actually is. Out of curiosity I opened it and only found 4 resistors soldered to the pins labeled 1, 4, 5 and 7. The other pins are not connected. Can you identify it from the photos? I would like to learn more about it.

The scale is in centimeters. 
[image: top view]
[image: opened]
[image: bottom view]
[image: side view]

Comment: It looks like its from 1988, f that really is a date code. :D Could it be that it was a test device they used to test the outputs of some kind of equipment? Would be nice if smóeone could actually tell where it was used. Maybe you could try and look somehow up the connector and then go from there.

Comment: It might be for testing relay sockets like this: https://www.morssmitt.com/uploads/images/catalog/product/detail/v25-relay-socket-heavy-duty-power-relay-nieaf-smitt(3).jpg

Comment: It's pretty definitely for testing *something*, at least, given that it has the word TEST in big letters across it.

Comment: @Andy, old boy, I'm surprised at you. You'll never know when you need to get a telex machine going again.

Comment: Funny you mention that......

Answer (score 5, accepted):

Something about it reminded me of a telex machine. Doing an image search led me to this:

[image]

*Photo 1. Merten 465108 ADO Telephone Socket 8/8–Pin/White. Image source: [Amazon](https://www.amazon.co.uk/Merten-465108-Telephone-Socket-8-Pin/dp/B001BB15LU).*

The pin numbering sequence match your connector. I can't figure out if it's country specific but there was something similar used in Ireland. They faded out of use by the early 1990s with the rise of the fax machine.

So, I reckon its a telex circuit test plug.

---

[image]

*Photo 2. A telex machine. Image source: [sv.wikipedia.org](https://sv.wikipedia.org/wiki/Telex#/media/Fil:Telexmaskin.jpg).*

> ADo 8
>
> (The Walzenstecker shown above was later succeeded by the more versatile 8-pin connector known as ADo 8.) This connector was used for a variety of equipment and had two 'coded' guide pins at the centre, to ensure that the plug is entered into the socket with the right side up, and to avoid the wrong plug being inserted into the wrong socket. The sockets are 'programmable'.

[image]

*Figure 1. Pinout. Source: [Crypto Museum](https://www.cryptomuseum.com/telex/).*

```
TX a (a1)
TX b (b1)
RX a (a2)
RX b (b2)
Bridge to 6 1
Bridge to 5 1
-
-
```

> The orientation of two small discs inside the socket can be altered in order to configure it for various applications. The image above shows the correct configuration for use with a teleprinter. Pins 1-4 are used for the same signals as on the earlier Walzenstecker. The bridge between pins 5 and 6 is optional 1 and is used on newer equipment to signal that the teleprinter is connected.

Source: [Crypto Museum](https://www.cryptomuseum.com/telex/).

Comment: I never knew what a telex is. Never even heard of it. Now I know. Thank you!

Comment: They're worth a little bit of looking into. Characters were transmitted in 5-bit ASCII generated mechanically by electric motors. 5-bit was as much as the asynchronous motors could be reasonably expected to keep in sync before the next start bit. You could store messages on punched tape for transmission later. Plenty of information on YouTube.

Comment: You could also [read about the telex network and teletype machines](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Telex) rather than listening to so yahoo dribbling out information at the rate of one fact per half an hour in a video.

Comment: Interesting those coded guide pins! I tried to decode the ones on my device: One face points up "A" and the other right "C" (when looking onto the bottom side, see [picture](https://www.blogpool.de/gfx/ado-key.jpg)). They definitively have a 90° angle. I did not find a code for that ([1](http://scz.bplaced.net/f3000.html), [2](https://de.wikipedia.org/wiki/Anschlussdose_(Telefon)#Schl%C3%BCsselstellung), [3](https://www.blogpool.de/informationstechnik/tae-ado/)). 

Comment: You've dug up more information then! I think you have passed out my knowledge on the subject by now. You should put a QR code on the plug to link to this article before caching it again.

Comment: Your answer inspired me to read more on this subject, thank you! I attached a QR code referencing to this Q&A, good idea!